# List database CONNECT privileges on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

How can I view database-level privileges like CONNECT of users?

I found 2 ways already, but neither of them is perfect:

Use function `has_database_privilege()`.

This works, but I have to run it manually for every user one by one:

```
SELECT has_database_privilege('david', 'postgres', 'connect');
```

---

This one seems to return an incomplete result. It returns `NULL` at first, but `david` and other users can still connect to `postgres` DB. Only after I run any `GRANT` command (and then `REVOKE` of course) on that DB, the table is filled with some result: `{=Tc/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}`. So I guess I have to `GRANT` and then `REVOKE` every time before I use this method?

```
SELECT datname as "Relation", 
       datacl as "Permissions" 
FROM pg_database 
WHERE datname = 'postgres';
```

Using PostgreSQL 10.9 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function as part of a select that retrieves all users:

```
SELECT rolname, has_database_privilege(rolname, 'postgres', 'connect')
from pg_roles
where rolcanlogin;
```

You can extend that, to show this information for every user in every database:

```
select db.datname, r.rolname, has_database_privilege(r.rolname, db.datname, 'connect')
from pg_roles r
  cross join pg_database db
where r.rolcanlogin
  and db.datallowconn
order by db.datname, r.rolname;
```